# Do I need to reserve space before installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I had Windows 7 32 bit on my existing system, but I am planning to install Ubuntu alongside it. So, I just decided to do a fresh installation of both the operating systems.

When I insert the Windows 7 DVD, I can create 3 partitions at maximum, with one being the one where Windows 7 will be installed.

I just wanted to know – do I need to keep some un-partitioned space for Ubuntu to install?

By "unpartitioned space" I mean the space left after creating 3 partitions for Windows 7. I have a 500 GB HDD, so the three partitions I would be creating are 120 GB, 120 GB and 120 GB. The rest is shown as some logical drive, is that unpartitioned space?

Can I install Ubuntu over there? I am pretty sure the space shown as logical won't be available as drives when I log into Windows 7.

Is that space lost or can I use that to install ubuntu?

Comment: Why are you going dual-boot when free Virtual Machine hypervisors such as [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/) and VMWare player are available?

Comment: @MikePennington Because a virtual machine never provides the same performance as a natively running system? That is really not the question here.

Comment: @slhck, with the [built-in virtualization on modern CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Hardware_assist), the virtualization penalty is generally less than 5% unless you are dealing with heavy Network or Disk IO.  My question is valid, since VM solutions are much more flexible than a dual-boot scenario

Comment: I would like to have it installed normally with dual boot. Not a big fan of Virtual Machine to be honest.

Comment: @CRMJunkie - Yes you need to safe a portion of your HDD for Linux

Comment: There is a partition editor built in to the Ubuntu installer, you just need to chose not to automatically partition everything and choose manual partitioning instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wanted to know – do I need to keep some un-partitioned space for Ubuntu to install?

Yes

> By "unpartitioned space" I mean the space left after creating 3 partitions for Windows 7. I have a 500 GB HDD, so the three partitions I would be creating are 120 GB, 120 GB and 120 GB...  Can I install Ubuntu over there?

Yes, use the unpartioned space after installing your NTFS partitions for Win7.  The ubuntu install CD will guide you and put [`GRUB`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) on the MBR.  [`GRUB`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) will allow you to switch between windows and linux after [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).  The [Ubuntu Dual Boot page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) may be of assistance as well.

Comment: So the space stated as logical will be actually used for ubuntu, right?

Comment: [Yes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643891)